# How to access data in this model class?

Tags: python, c, numpy, python-class

I'm using package `libmf` to do parallel non-negative matrix factorization, i.e., X = WH. I use the method `fit` from the class `MF`. As mentioned in below description, the resulting matrices are stored in `MF.model`.

```
def fit(self, X):
    """
    factorize the i x j data matrix X into (j, k) (k, i) sized matrices stored in MF.model
    :param X: (n, 3) shaped numpy array [known index and values of the data matrix]
    """
    ensure_width(X, 3)
    d = X.astype(np.float32)
    data_p = d.ctypes.data_as(c_float_p)
    nnx = ctypes.c_int(X.shape[0])
    mf.fit_interface.restype = ctypes.POINTER(MFModel)
    mf.fit_interface.argtypes = (ctypes.c_int, c_float_p, options_ptr)
    out = mf.fit_interface(nnx, data_p, self._options)
    self.model = out.contents
```

From the [GitHub page](https://github.com/PorkShoulderHolder/python-libmf/blob/master/libmf/mf.py) of the package, the class `MFModel` is

```
class MFModel(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("fun", ctypes.c_int),
                ("m", ctypes.c_int),
                ("n", ctypes.c_int),
                ("k", ctypes.c_int),
                ("b", ctypes.c_float),
                ("P", c_float_p),
                ("Q", c_float_p)]
```

Could you explain how to extract information from this class?

```
# !pip install libmf
import numpy as np
from libmf import mf

X = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [0, 11, 0],
              [5, 0, 7]])

row, col = X.nonzero()
values = X[np.nonzero(X)]
res = np.array(list(zip(row.tolist(), col.tolist(), values.tolist())))

engine = mf.MF(k = 2)
engine.fit(res)
engine.model
```

For convenience, I also put the notebook on Colab [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Z_AoiAzoG-r3QDM2pojolyDvqPW_zZsh?usp=sharing).

Comment: `model.P` and `model.Q` are pointers to float arrays `P` and `Q`

Comment: @Marat If I use `engine.model.P` instead of `engine.model`, I got `<libmf.mf.LP_c_float at 0x7ff8351fa950>`. Could you explain how to get `P` and `Q` in usual numpy array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not that deep in that library but here are a few observations that might be interesting: (Building on top of the code provided)

#### TL;DR

You can either use the `engine.q_factors;engine.p_factors` to obtain the `P;Q` matrices or you can iterate through `engine.model.P[i]`:

```
print(engine.p_factors())
# [[0.37909135 0.70226544]
#  [2.561905   2.0429273 ]
#  [1.7700745  2.0010414 ]]
print(engine.model.P[0:(engine.model.m * engine.model.k)])
# [0.37909135222435, 0.7022654414176941, 2.5619049072265625, 2.0429272651672363, 1.770074486732483, 2.0010414123535156]
```

#### 1. P/Q-Factors Methods

The object `engine` has two interesting methods: `p_factors;q_factors`. In our setup, these methods spit out two `(3, 2)` matrices:

```
P = engine.p_factors()
P
# array([[0.37909135, 0.70226544],
#        [2.561905  , 2.0429273 ],
#        [1.7700745 , 2.0010414 ]], dtype=float32)
Q = engine.q_factors()
Q
# array([[0.87586826, 1.6112198 ],
#        [2.5359864 , 2.095469  ],
#        [1.6843219 , 2.0822709 ]], dtype=float32)
```

The immediate reaction is: *Let's multiply!*

```
RES = np.matmul(P, Q.transpose())
RES
# array([[ 1.463538 ,  2.432946 ,  2.1008186],
#        [ 5.535496 , 10.777846 ,  8.569    ],
#        [ 4.7744694,  8.682005 ,  7.1480856]], dtype=float32)
```

Now, I'm not deep enough in the (usage of the) library and topic to give an educated assessment of that product.

#### 2. Methods Source Code

The next step is to investigate the two methods `p-q_factors`. Here is the source code (`MF.p_factors`):

```
def p_factors(self):
    if self.model is None:
        return LookupError("no model data is saved, try running model.mf_fit(...) first")
    out = np.zeros(self.model.m * self.model.k)
    out = out.astype(np.float32)
    mf.get_P(ctypes.c_void_p(out.ctypes.data), ctypes.byref(self.model))
    return out.reshape((self.model.m, self.model.k))
```

This is somewhat underwhelming as it seems the interesting stuff happens in `mf.get_P` where mf is the underlying c++ library.

#### 3. C++

Continuing our quest, the source code of `mf.get_P` (in `libmf_interface.cpp) reads:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" float* get_P(float *out, mf::mf_model *model)
#else
float* get_P(float *out, mf::mf_model *model)
#endif
{
    for (int i = 0; i < model->m; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < model->k; j++){
            int idx = i * model->k + j;
            out[idx] = model->P[idx];
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

This code (very) roughly translates to

```
def get_P(out, model: mf.MFMODEL) -> np.ndarray:
    for i in range(model.m):
        for j in range(model.k):
            idx = i * model.k + j
            out[idx] = model.P[idx]
    return out
```

which seems to access data from `model.P` via indices.

And hence you can access the data as follows `engine.model.P[i]`.